# ¿como subir imagen a la base de datos mysql con php?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, funciones

Que tal estoy practicando programación y estoy haciendo un formulario que suba datos e imágenes el formulario funcionaba bien hasta que decidí implementar el subir imágenes desde ahí cuando le doy a  darle al botón subir no realiza la acción no la sube a la base de datos.
el siguiente código es una función que estoy realizando para subir mis datos:

```
  public function subirPublicaion($titulo,$contenido,$image,$user){
  global $pdo;
   //user_id es para saber quien esta subiendo la publicaron 
   $user_id = $pdo->prepare("
           SELECT user_id 
           FROM user 
           WHERE user_id = :user");
    $user_id->execute([
         'user' => $user
       ]);

   $user_id = $user_id->fetch();

  //variable para guardar la imagen
   $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  
  $query = $pdo->prepare("
          INSERT INTO post(titulo,contenido,image,user_id,fecha)
          VALUES(:titulo, :contenido, :image,:user_id, :fecha)");

  $query->execute([
       'titulo' => $titulo,
       'contenido'  => $contenido,
       'image' =>  $image,
       'user_id' => $user_id['user_id'],
       'fecha'  => time()
       ]);

  if ($query) {
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
```

}

y este es mi formulario:
donde llamo a mi función subirPublicaion()
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta es mi tabla que uso en mi  base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es muy mala práctica guardar el archivo de imagen en la BBDD. En su lugar te recomiendo encarecidamente que guardes el archivo en un directorio del proyecto (uploads por ej) y en la BBDD guarda únicamente la ruta relativa del archivo dentro de la carpeta uploads. Te vas a quitar muchos problemas en el futuro.

Comment: lo que intentas es guardar el contenido de la imagen en la base de datos, cuando realmente lo que te interesa es guardar la imagen en un directorio del servidor y almacenar la ruta de este directorio junto a su nombre en la base de datos. Es decir: Guardas la imagen subida en Uploads/ Y lo que guardarías en la base de datos en el campo image sería: Uploads/nombre_imagen.extensión

Comment: Para nada recomendable guardar imágenes en la BBDD, si bien el motor lo permite no es muy eficiente ya que cada imagen pesa exponencialmente mas que un dato tipo text, yo hace un tiempo hice un programa para dicho fin, pero solo para ver la factibilidad, lo mejor es guardar las rutas relativas y luego llamarlas a través del código.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vas a introducir la imagen dentro de la base de datos entonces debes leer el contenido del archivo de la siguiente forma haciendo uso de, por ejemplo, la función [`file_get_contents()`](https://php.net/file_get_contents):

```
/* Cargamos el contenido del archivo en la variable */
$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
  
$query = $pdo->prepare("
    INSERT INTO post (
        titulo, contenido, image, user_id, fecha
    ) VALUES (
        :titulo, :contenido, :image,:user_id, :fecha
    )
");
$query->execute([
    'titulo' => $titulo,
    'contenido'  => $contenido,
    'image' =>  $image,
    'user_id' => $user_id['user_id'],
    'fecha'  => time(),
]);
```

Aunque esto arregla el problema de guardar una imagen en la base de datos, es menos eficiente guardar y obtener un archivo de una base de datos que hacer todo desde el sistema de archivos. Te recomiendo que copies ese archivo a un directorio y, posteriormente, enlaces al usuario a dicho archivo de manera directa en vez de ejecutar un PHP para obtener el archivo desde la base de datos y, posteriormente, enviarlo al navegador del usuario.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda